# Extract the name of a Database which is used in a view (refering other Database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

i dynamicaly create Views which refering other Databases (mainly to import data from there)

> use [RezepteDB]

in this DB i create a view like this

> CREATE VIEW [dbo].bla as select * from ZutatenDB.dbo.Bla

Later i need the name of the Database, on which is the view based.

For this example 'ZutatenDB'.

How can i done this? a small function to pass the name of the view and return the name of the database.

Comment: The easiest way is to add an extra column of database name in your view.

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to use [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](http://tem-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.bla', 'OBJECT');
```

You can see the referenced server, database, schema and objects.

Comment: the version with DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName]  does not work, bebause is list the name where the view is created instead which DB is refered.

Comment: @ozz yes, you are right - you can get the database name on creation and hard code the value in the view definition.